# How do you define direction of relationship using GQLAlchemy and can it be undirected/bidirectional?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I write Cypher query, I can set the direction of the relationship:

```
CREATE (:Country {name: 'France'})<-[l:WORKING_IN]-(p)-[w:LIVING_IN]->(:Country {name: 'Germany'})
```

I know that with GQLAlchemy I need to use the methods `to()` and `from()` after `create()`. I suppose that this sets the direction of the relationship.

But is it possible to create an undirected/bidirectional relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a bidirectional relationship, because bidirectional relationships are not supported when creating a relationship. In Memgraph, it is only possible to create directed relationships. If you are doing some kind of matching with the bidirectional pattern such as:

```
MATCH (:Country {name: 'France'})-[l:WORKING_IN]-(p)-[w:LIVING_IN]-(:Country {name: 'Germany'})
```

Memgraph is actually looking for both `->` and `<-` relationships, that is, both in and out relationships.